# (Haskell) Converting a functions type into maybe

Tags: haskell, option-type

given a function that does: (a -> a) We should take the function and convert it's type into (Maybe a -> Maybe a). I am kinda sitting here trying everything possible but I only got as far as getting the type Maybe (a -> a) but I don't get the idea of changing the actual Input and Output. So could someone give me only some hints or ideas on solving this problem so I can try it on my own? Thanks.

Comment: Check out the type signature of `fmap`, and see if you can make it do anything interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have

```
f :: a -> a
```

And you need to construct

```
g :: Maybe a -> Maybe a
g = ...
```

How we can construct it? First, it is a function of one argument, so it should be something like:

```
g = \x -> ...
```

Second, we have an argument of type `Maybe`, so we can analyze two cases separately:

```
g = \x -> case x of
  Nothing -> ... (1)
  Just y -> ... (2)
```

In (1), we can't do much: we can't produce a value of abstract type `a`, so can't use `Just`. The only thing we can use is `Nothing`.

In (2), we have three options:

a) `Nothing` again, so we get a boring solution:

```
g = \x -> case x of
  Nothing -> Nothing
  Just y -> Nothing
```

which is simply

```
g = \x -> Nothing
```

b) Or, we have a `y::a`, so we can return `Just y`:

```
g = \x -> case x of
  Nothing -> Nothing
  Just y -> Just y
```

which is simply

```
g = \x -> x -- = id
```

c) Or, we can apply `f` to `y`, to get a new value of type `a`. All we need to do then is to wrap this value in a `Just`:

```
g = \x -> case x of
  Nothing -> Nothing
  Just y -> Just (f y)
```

As @chi pointed out, we can keep applying `f` to the result, so we can also return `Just (f (f ... (f y)...))` for any number of `f`s.

Only (c) ever uses `f`, so it is the only non-trivial solution here.

*For the sake of completeness, it's worth noting that for real world application, both (b) and (c) are equivalent, as `f` can't be anything except `id`.*

As @amalloy pointed out, this is not the case if we take `f` as an argument instead of global function, as only `id` can serve as `a->a` for any `a`, but there are many functions with type `a->a` *for given `a`*. So if your `g` supposed to be

```
g :: (a->a)->(Maybe a->Maybe a)
```

Then (b) and (c) are no longer the same thing.

For sure, this can be written in many ways: the naive version above, using the fact `Maybe` is a `Monad`, using `fmap` from `Functor Maybe` (credits to @amalloy), but the result will be the same.

Comment: Very nice. If we wanted to be very pedantic, we can also return `Just (f (f ... (f y)...))` for any number of `f`s. (Not a common result, but if we want to be exhaustive...)

Comment: There is only one function with the exact type `a -> a`, but there are many many functions that *unify* with that type, such as `succ` or `(* 2)`. (b) and (c) are nowhere near equivalent for an arbitrary `f`.

Comment: @amalloy, true, if we are talking about `forall a . f :: a->a`, but my assumption is based on `f :: forall a . a->a`.

Comment: That's a strange assumption to make, since as you point out there is only one such function, and it's not the type that Haskell infers when you accept `f` as an argument to your function.

Comment: @amalloy, of course your are correct, making `f` global just simplifies explanation a bit without loss of generality, and I put a note just to point out that one strange thing. Edited now to incorporate your point.

Answer (score 2):

It's really tough to avoid the final answer to this, because it's a trivial problem, really.

Check out the signature of the standard function `fmap` (I'll drop the constraint part, since we don't need it now):

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

You can look at it as on a function of two arguments `(a -> b)` and `f a`, producing a result `f b`. However the following signature is absolutely the same:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)
```

Do the bells start ringing? Yes, `fmap` can also be seen as a function of one argument `(a -> b)` producing the `(f a -> f b)` function as a result.

Now, the `f` in those signatures represents any type that has an instance of `Functor`, of which `Maybe` is just the case. Now, figure out the rest :)